# I want to process a large file containing json object on each line using jq

Tags: json, group-by, aggregate, jq

I want to aggregate the json present on each line of file based on the date and account. There might be multiple records with same date and account, we have to aggregate count based on date and account_no.

sample file:

```
{"date":"2019-04-01","count":0,"account_no":"1591"}
{"date":"2019-04-01","count":1,"account_no":"1592"}
```

Please suggest some solution.
Number of jsons in file are almost 2.5cr

Comment: This is too broad. You should make the attempt yourself and then post a question asking how to overcome specific problems that you encounter.

Comment: What does "2.5cr" signify?  Also, in future, please follow the [mcve] guidelines. In particular, some details about the expected output should be given.

Comment: I have used this command.. But its time consuming for large scale data

**
head -100 report_data  | jq --slurp . | jq '[(group_by(.account_no )[] | { account_no: .[0].account_no , count: map(.count )|add, TYPE: "total" })]' | jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ]])[] | @csv' > processData.csv
**

Answer (score 1):

jq using `inputs` is a good way to go.

First, here's a generic stream-oriented `sigma_by` function:

```
# In this formulation, f must either always evaluate to a string or
# always to an integer, it being understood that negative integers
# might be problematic
def sigma_by(s; f; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|f] += ($x|g));
```

Then a solution could be achieved by:

```
sigma_by(inputs; "\(.date):\(.account_no)"; .count)
```

provided the -n command-line option is used.

### Output

With the sample input, the output would be:

```
{
  "2019-04-01:1591": 0,
  "2019-04-01:1592": 1
}
```

### Variations

Needless to say, there are many possible variations. In particular, a variant of `sigma_by` that uses a dictionary of dictionaries might be warranted, e.g. to save space, and to avoid potential parsing issues for recovering the two "aggregate by" strings:

```
def sigma_by(s; a; b; g):
  reduce s as $x  (null; .[$x|a][$x|b] += ($x|g));

sigma_by(inputs; .date; .account_no; .count)
```

Note that jq's builtin "group_by" has a significant potential disadvantage for large arrays: it uses a sorting algorithm.